Unable to create GCP Composer environment - "Some of the GKE pods failed to become healthy"
Unable to create GCP Composer environment - "Some of the GKE pods failed to become healthy". How to resolve this?
I have configured the setting and gave the necessary access. But it failed to create the environment. Can anyone help into this?

Have you more error logs ? can access to Cloud Logging and check all the logs that concern cloud-commposer-environment and with the error severity. You maybe have a permission issue.

Check your network's subnets, if GKE can't spin up enough nodes then you have such issues. Please follow this link for more details about how to configure your network

Since upgrading to composer-2.7.0-airflow-2.7.3 I had similar issues with environment and web-server health. I found that the scheduler/work/web-servers do not play well with the default memory limit now (0.5Gb) - at least on the small environment size. Upping the memory under resources for both the scheduler and web server worked for me.

Use the large one. Still the same issue.
